# How can I write my own function for matching string patterns?

Tags: string, rust, pattern-matching

I'm trying to [replace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.replace) all non-alphanumeric characters in a `String` with `_`. So far, I've figured out how to do the opposite:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("hello!");
    println!("{}", sanitize(a)); // prints "_____!"
}


fn sanitize(check: String) -> String {
    check.replace(char::is_alphanumeric, "_")
}
```

When I try to invert the `Pattern` on the `check.replace` line, I get an error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("hello!");
    println!("{}", sanitize(a)); // should print "hello_"
}


fn sanitize(check: String) -> String {
    check.replace(!char::is_alphanumeric, "_")
}
```

```
error[E0600]: cannot apply unary operator `!` to type `fn(char) -> bool {char::methods::<impl char>::is_alphanumeric}`
   --> src/main.rs:146:19
    |
146 |     check.replace(!char::is_alphanumeric, "_")
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot apply unary operator `!`
```

What would be the syntax for inverting this `Pattern`, so that I can replace non-alphanumeric characters?

I notice in the documentation for [matches](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches) that `char::is_alphanumeric` is a valid `Pattern` because it is "a function or closure that determines if a character matches". I presume I could write my own function if needed, but are there are restrictions on how that function should be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be to use a closure (unless you really need a separate function that you use in multiple places). As you've seen in the docs, the pattern can be "a function or closure" which matches the signature [`FnMut(char) -> bool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html#impl-Pattern%3C%27a%3E-5). Using a closure that simply negates `char::is_alphanumeric` would look like this:

```
fn sanitize(check: String) -> String {
    check.replace(|c| !char::is_alphanumeric(c), "_")
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I was hoping there was some native syntax for this. Hadn't gotten to that section of the book yet!

Comment: `!c.is_alphanumeric()`  looks simpler

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a custom function can be used anywhere that a `Pattern` is required so long as it takes a `char` as its only argument, and returns a `bool`. [Doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html#impl-Pattern%3C%27a%3E-5):

```rust
impl<'a, F> Pattern<'a> for F where
    F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
```

In my case, I ended up with the below:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("hello!");
    println!("{}", sanitize(a)); // should print "hello_"
}


fn sanitize(check: String) -> String {
    check.replace(evil_chars, "_")
}

fn evil_chars(c: char) -> bool {
    !char::is_alphanumeric(c)
}
```